# iCarousel, how to go/scroll programatically to next item?

Tags: ios7, storyboard, xcode5, icarousel

I just need to change/scroll or go to next item of the caroussel programatically when the user clicks on a button. I have searched how to do it without success.

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution, here is the code of my button action:

```
- (IBAction)onBurning:(id)sender {
    [_carousel scrollByNumberOfItems:1 duration:1.0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**  and the last version of iCarousel pod

```
carouselView.scrollToItem(at: 1, animated: true)
```

or

```
carouselView.scrollToItem(at: 1, duration: 1.0)
```